# Appropriate datetime.time inputs

Tags: python-3.x

I think I am misunderstanding how datetime inputs are taken, it looks like a tuple but isn't apparently, please can someone explain why this doesn't work?

```
print(datetime.date(2000, 1, 1))

date1  = 1, 1, 2000
print(datetime.date(date1))

>2000-01-01 
>Error message: an integer is required (got type tuple)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is due to this line `date1  = 1, 1, 2000`. Basically what is wrong is that when you have the commas like that it turns the variable into a tuple, which is not variable type you want. How you would fix this is using a list:

```
print(datetime.date(2000, 1, 1))
date1  = [1, 1, 2000]
print(datetime.date(date1[0],date1[1],date1[2]))
```

Hope I helped!

-Zeus